# Replacing duplicate Field for elimination - Flutter Form Builder error

Tags: flutter, formbuilder

I'm using **flutter_form_builder** and I want to **build a dynamic form**, such as answering Yes or No on a Widget and then having another Widget pop-up right below it.

For instance: "Did the patient eat anything?" Yes/No. If yes, show a widget with checkboxes "What did they eat?" Rice, pizza, etc.

The problem is that FormBuilder is throwing warnings when I'm changing the diuresis Radio:
I/flutter (21285): Warning! Replacing duplicate Field for activities -- this is OK to ignore as long as the field was intentionally replaced
I/flutter (21285): Warning! Replacing duplicate Field for elimination -- this is OK to ignore as long as the field was intentionally replaced
I/flutter (21285): Warning! Ignoring Field unregistration for elimination -- this is OK to ignore as long as the field was intentionally replaced

**The main issue:** So, what happens on the UI is. Let's say I select "Sim" for the "elimination" card
and then I change my selection on the "diuresis" card, then it throws the error above,
the screen rebuilds and the elimination card appears unselected.

My code is below. (HMClickableCard is just a widget that has a card and implements FormBuilderRadioGroup inside it)

```
Container(
            child: HMClickableCard(
                options: ["Sim", "Não"],
                label: "Diurese",
                name: "diuresis",
                icon: Icons.bathroom,
                iconSize: 30,
                onChanged: (option) {
                  _fbKey.currentState?.save();
                  setState(() {
                    switch (option) {
                      case "Sim":
                        _diuresis = true;
                        break;
                      case "Não":
                        _diuresis = false;
                        break;
                    }
                  });
                }),
          ),
            Container(
                child: FormBuilderCheckboxGroup(
              name: "diuresisAspect",
              options: [
                FormBuilderFieldOption(value: "Clara"),
                FormBuilderFieldOption(value: "Amarelo Ouro"),
                FormBuilderFieldOption(value: "Avermelhada"),
                FormBuilderFieldOption(value: "Odor forte"),
                FormBuilderFieldOption(value: "Queixa de dor ao urinar"),
              ],
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: "Aspecto da diurese",
                  labelStyle:
                      TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
            )),
          Container(
              child: HMClickableCard(
            options: ["Sim", "Não"],
            label: "Eliminação Intestinal",
            name: "elimination",
            icon: Icons.ac_unit,
            iconSize: 30,
            onChanged: (_option) {
              _fbKey.currentState?.save();
              setState(() {
                switch (_option) {
                  case "Sim":
                    _intestinalElimination = true;
                    break;
                  case "Não":
                    _intestinalElimination = false;
                    break;
                }
              });
            },
          )),
            Container(
                child: FormBuilderCheckboxGroup(
              name: "eliminationAspect",
              options: [
                FormBuilderFieldOption(value: "Bolinhas"),
                FormBuilderFieldOption(
                    value: "Moldadas (forma de salsicha)"),
                FormBuilderFieldOption(value: "Pastosa"),
                FormBuilderFieldOption(value: "Líquida")
              ],
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: "Aspecto da eliminação intestinal:",
                  labelStyle:
                      TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
            )),
```

**Does anybody know how to solve this?**
I googled and could only find things related to different keys (I'm only using a GlobalKey for the entire form) or same name for the FormFields (which as you can see is not the case)